# PostgreSQL: PANIC: heap2_redo: unknown op code 32

Tags: postgresql, error-log, write-ahead-logging

I was doing migrations while the server was still accessing the slave DB. I have a master / slave setup. After I restarted the server, I realized I couldn't connect to the SLAVE anymore. I went into the SLAVE and tried restarting Postgres, this is what it returned:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql start
 * Starting PostgreSQL 9.3 database server                                       
 * The PostgreSQL server failed to start. Please check the log output:
2014-12-16 22:14:20 UTC LOG:  database system was interrupted while in recovery at log time 2014-12-16 20:57:20 UTC
2014-12-16 22:14:20 UTC HINT:  If this has occurred more than once some data might be corrupted and you might need to choose an earlier recovery target.
2014-12-16 22:14:20 UTC LOG:  entering standby mode
2014-12-16 22:14:20 UTC LOG:  redo starts at 0/38620168
2014-12-16 22:14:20 UTC LOG:  consistent recovery state reached at 0/38680BF0
2014-12-16 22:14:20 UTC LOG:  database system is ready to accept read only connections
2014-12-16 22:14:20 UTC PANIC:  heap2_redo: unknown op code 32
2014-12-16 22:14:20 UTC CONTEXT:  xlog redo UNKNOWN
2014-12-16 22:14:21 UTC LOG:  startup process (PID 18357) was terminated by signal 6: Aborted
2014-12-16 22:14:21 UTC LOG:  terminating any other active server processes
```

Any idea on what could be causing this and what I can do to fix this? I'm going into a PANIC frenzy.

Comment: What exact versions are you upgrade from and to?  Which are you upgrading first?

Comment: @jjanes Thanks for the quick reply, I'm not upgrading to anything. I already had streaming replication set up. I made some changes to the tables and I couldn't connect to the slave. The master is still working but the slave refuses to start

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/release-9-3-3.html

> Fixing this required changing the WAL record format for tuple
>   freezing. While this is no issue for standalone servers, when using
>   replication it means that standby servers must be upgraded to 9.3.3 or
>   later before their masters are. An older standby will be unable to
>   interpret freeze records generated by a newer master, and will fail
>   with a PANIC message. (In such a case, upgrading the standby should be
>   sufficient to let it resume execution.)

Comment: both the master and the slave are running 9.3.2, I didn't update the version of postgres, I simply made a bunch of table migrations, added new columns and tables.

Comment: Are you positive?  This is exactly the error message you would get when replaying WAL from 9.3.3 into a 9.3.2 server.

Comment: Yeap, I ran psql -V on both the master and the slave and both machines returned the following: psql (PostgreSQL) 9.3.2

Comment: To clarify, I had my web servers running while I was doing the table migrations. The changes propagated to the master no problem, but perhaps during the transmission to the slave, a READ operation on the slave was made and therefore corrupted the DB? What do you think?

Comment: psql -V might be misleading, as it tells you what client you are using and not necessarily what server.  They could be different.  start psql connecting to your server, and then do `select version();`.  This will tell out about the server.  In any case, you shouldn't be using 9.3.2, it had some nasty (but thankfully mostly rare) bugs.